# remove function returning false for record that should be in hash table

Tags: c++, hashmap, logic, hashtable

I am making a hash table that uses linear probing as the collision resolution method. I have tested my other functions and they are working as intended, I just can't seem to figure out what's going wrong in the remove. I am attempting to use the lazy deletion strategy of just having a bool flag marked as deleted or not in the records. I assume i am missing a logical step somewhere since the key that should be removed is apparently not found when passed to the function.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems with `remove`.

The main one is that your `idx` calculation is wrong in your loop.  It should be

```
int idx = (hash + i) % LargerMax;
```

like you have in `update`.

You're not handling deleted records right.  Think about what your list looks like if you insert two records (A, then B) that have the smae hash value, then delete record A.  How do you find B?  (Ponder this before reading on.)

As you walk thru `records_`, when you find a deleted node, you need to skip it and move on to the next one.  Only stop searching when you find a NULL record.

You also need to `return false` at the end of the function, if you've searched thru all the nodes and didn't find it.

Comment: thanks, I will take your advice and try it out now. Will report back.

Comment: any pseudo code for :(A, then B) that have the smae hash value, then delete record A. How do you find B? (Ponder this before reading on.?

Comment: having trouble figuring out the logical implementation

Comment: @user7795742 Answer: You can't find B, because your search stops when it gets to the deleted A record.

Comment: ok the remove is working it seems.... but now when i use my find() it crashes when searching a removed word :D

Comment: @user7795742 Why'd you remove the code from the question?  As it stands now it should be closed.